# HTML javascript not able to destoy nth element by id

Tags: javascript, html, express, bootstrap-4

I am new to javascript and HTML. I developed website using node + express backend and using bootstrap + html + JS in front end. I have created few cards using BS4. It looks like following [image]

Code:

```
<section id="cards">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-deck text-center">
            <div class="card shadow-sm" id="mainCards">
                <div class="card-header" id="mainCardHeader">
                    <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Total Cases</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title"><%= areaTotal%></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card shadow-sm" id="mainCards">
                <div class="card-header"  id="mainCardHeader">
                    <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Last 30 days</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title"><%= arealast30%></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card shadow-sm" id="mainCards">
                <div class="card-header" id="mainCardHeader">
                    <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Last 7 days</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title"><%= arealast7%></h1>
                </div>
            </div>                
            <div class="card shadow-sm" id="mainCards">
                <div class="card-header"  id="mainCardHeader">
                    <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Growth</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title"><%= areaR%></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card shadow-sm" id="mainCards">
                <div class="card-header"  id="mainCardHeader">
                    <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Deaths</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title"><%= areaDeaths%></h1>
                </div>
            </div>             
        </div>
    </div>    
</section>
```

I want to add one more card if count>0. I have created external div before 5th card and it is working fine with following script.

```
var deathCount = <%- areaDeaths%>;
if (deathCount == 0){
    document.getElementById("divDeath").style.display = "none";
};
```

However new card is not aligned correctly. Is it anyway I can make 5th element of such id disappear without harming alignment of these cards.

tried so far:

```
var deathCount = <%- areaDeaths%>;
if (deathCount == 0){
    var elements = document.getElementById("mainCards").children;
    elements.item(4).style.display = "none";
};
```

Comment: You can't use the same id in multiple elements. Using id seems easier at the beginning, but it's not good practice. Use it, if you really need it. What do you mean by "without harming alignment"? It would be better if you put images of the 5-cards version and the design you want to achieve.

Comment: @BülentAkgül  I have tried selecting name instead of id, Name was unique for last value it is still not disappearing.

Comment: Without harming alignment means, if you remove one card from container rest of four card should occupy rest of the space and space should not be left blank on right side.

Comment: It can be done by CSS. card-deck should have display: flex, card should have flex:1. and remove width from the card.